# ClassNotFoundException for com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

this is a repeated question, I know.

But All those questions are seemingly little unrelated to mine or they're ages old.

Steps I've done which I've learnt from previous SO questions and other resources

1.Download sqljdbc driver and add it to class path. I've kept that in

```
C:\projects\tomcat\webapps\testingfiles\java_files>echo %CLASS_PATH%
C:\projects\tomcat\lib;C:\xampp\tomcat\lib;C:\Program Files\Java;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_112;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112;C:\projects\tomcat\webapps\testingfiles\WEB-INF\lib\sqljdbc4-3.0.jar
```

1. Here is my sample code

   ```
   import java.sql.DriverManager;
   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.ResultSet;
   import java.sql.SQLException;
   import java.sql.Statement;

   public class Main {

           public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
               Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  
               Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://grddwmrtwhqipdw;user=ipdwro;password=readonly;database=IPDW_Prod02");
               System.out.println("test");
               Statement sta = conn.createStatement();
               String Sql = "select * from testing_table";
               ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery(Sql);
               while (rs.next()) {
                   System.out.println(rs.getString("txt_title"));
               }
           }
       }
   ```

   3. And here is my exception

> C:\projects\tomcat\webapps\testingfiles\java_files>java Main Exception
>   in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
>
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>
> at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>
> at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
>
> at Main.main(Main.java:10)

P.S please do not downvote this question because it is repeated, I've searched most of the SO questions and none of them actually were helpful for my cause, thanks!

Comment: you can't do it. You just saved the lib in `WEB-INF\lib`. When tomcat starts, then the lib while be loaded. But now you use a `main` function to start your application, then the `ClaasLoade` will not load the lib. You need to use `Junit` to test your application.

Comment: According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html, CLASSPATH is the valid name. By the way, it is better set class path per application like this java -classpath C:\java\a.jar;C:\java\b.jar com.test.YourMainClass

Comment: @JonahCui starting tomcat is not relevant to this question, I'm just saving them there for future means.

Comment: @PWC Yes, I've seen this suggestion in other SO answers, it does not change the exception I get, but, as an optimist, I am guessing you want me to use 
`javac -cp .;C:/path/to/sqljdbc42.jar; Main.java` right? If yes, then, I must say, I am getting the same exception

Comment: Your command is not valid, it should be `java -cp .;C:/path/to/sqljdbc42.jar; Main`. `javac` for compilation, `java` run the compiled class

Comment: @PWC that is new to me, it worked thank you, might I ask, If this were to act like a servlet in tomcat(future use right now thanks to your answer) , how will this command be executed?

Comment: you don't need to execute such command. Like @JonahCui said put the jar in `WEB-INF/lib` is just enough.

Answer (score 0):

Did you placed 'sqljdbc4-3.0.jar' in your project's lib folder and deployed it?
If YES try placing the JAR in TOMCAT's LIB folder "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib" and check once.